# Fillin char array with characters of a bigger array | @ASSEMBLY IA32

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Good evening, i'm trying to translate this code of mine from C to assembly IA32:

```
int i=0;
char s[3]; char c[n];   
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    s[i]=c[i];
}
```

n is a char that receives a value from user. By the time this "for" it's executing "c" is already filled with chars. I want, as you can see, fill "s" with the three first entries of "c". I translated this code to assembly like this:

```
.data
is: .asciz "%s"
id: .asciz "%d"
.bss
.comm c,500,1
.comm s,500,1
.comm n,4,4
.global main
 main:
  #asking for string to fill "c"
   pushl $c
   pushl $is
   call scanf
   addl $8,%esp
   #asking for integer to know how long is c
   pushl $n
   pushl $id
   call scanf
   addl $8,%esp
   movl $0,%eax
   for:
    cmpl $3,%eax
    jge endfor
    movb c(%eax),%cl
    movb %cl,s(%eax)
    incl %eax
    jmp for

endfor:
    movl  $0,%eax
    pushl %eax
    pushl $s
    pushl $is
    call printf
    addl $8,%ebp
    popl %eax
```

Thing is when i execute this code it doesn't print anything at all, it's like "s" array it's empty, i've tried several things and nothing has worked so far. Any assembly genius to give me a hand?

:-) Thanks!

Comment: Why don’t You use a C compiler for reference?

Comment: I tried with an online disassembler, but code it's not for human (me) to understand it, totally weird. :(

Comment: Use C compiler to translate C code to assembly.

Comment: i don't know how to do it, i used to know it but with optimizations (i don't know anymore), i also need it with 0 optimizations, can you give me a hand with that? i've been looking for a post that teach that but haven't found it yet

Comment: `char c[n];` is uninitialized?

Comment: Yes and no. User set n's value before i create char c[n]

Comment: Write a valid C code and put it into a function. On Linux to compile to to assembly: `cc -m32 -S -O1 a_file.c` . This should generate a_file.s with assembly code. Without optimisations the code is of very low quality.

Comment: I said this optimizations things because some1 told that +optimizations->less understanding of code.. Now i have to ask: is that  true?

Comment: Yes and no. Without optimizations you get lot of assembly code with many "not needed" instructions, like after change of some variable it gets written into it's memory, and the immediately read back into register for next operation, etc... If you get used to it, debug code is actually not that hard to read, as the way how C compiles is quite "static" in debug. With some non-aggressive optimizations you get assembly code which is much closer to what would human write, with only very few useless instructions, and most of them just implementing what you wrote in source.

Comment: There's just risk the optimizer is too good for you, and you will have hard time to understand some of the shortcuts it did use. I think checking the O1/O2 code may be a good hint to learn how to write efficient Assembly, but when completely lost, you can check debug, to see the C source in raw 1:1 translated way. For training purposes you should try both. *"totally weird"* = yeah, debug code is that, but it has some inner logic, once you will know enough about asm, it will be possible to work through it, it's just tedious then.

Comment: BTW, your code is hopefully not complete (missing eax init), so who knows what goes wrong, you don't show how you init c[n]. Try it in debugger and check the register values and memory view.

Comment: G. Morning, Ped7g. Thanks for helping. Few questions: should i add : "cc -m32 -S -02 a_file.c" for a dissassemble code with O2 optimizations?  I will also include how  is working c[n]. And by debugger you mean gdb?

Comment: You need an [MCVE]. When I add just enough to your code to be able to assemble and run it, the array copy part works fine. The output from `printf` is not visible because it is not flushed before the program crashes, which you can change by (a) putting a new line at the end of the string and especially by (b) returning properly from `main` and not crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked fine for me:

```
.data
is: .asciz "%s"
id: .asciz "%d"
.bss
.comm c,500,1
.comm s,500,1
.comm n,4,4
.text
.global main
 main:
  #asking for string to fill "c"
   pushl $c
   pushl $is
   call scanf
   addl $8,%esp
   #asking for integer to know how long is c
   pushl $n
   pushl $id
   call scanf
   addl $8,%esp
   movl $0,%eax
   for:
    cmpl $3,%eax
    jge endfor
    movb c(%eax),%cl
    movb %cl,s(%eax)
    incl %eax
    jmp for

endfor:
    movl  $0,%eax
    pushl %eax
    pushl $s
    pushl $is
    call printf
    addl $8,%esp
    popl %eax
    ret
```

- Code belongs in .text, not in .bss
- `addl $8,%ebp` near end should have been `addl $8,%esp` to fix stack pointer after `printf` call
- needed `ret` at the end of `main`
- you probably should explicitly store a nul terminator at the end of the string (unless you're expecting to copy it from the source string). I didn't make that change, however.

I don't think I changed anything else.

Assembled and linked with:

```
as -g -32 test.s -o test.o
gcc -g -m32 test.o
```

Input:

```
abc 3
```

Output:

```
abc
```